# Vue js conditional statement inside axios fetch API

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a vue-router like this

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import http from './helpers/http';
import Home from './views/Home/Home.vue';
import HomeMentor from './views/Home/HomeMentor.vue';


const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: '',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Container" */ './components/Container.vue'),
      children: [
        {
          path: '/',
          name: 'Dashboard',
            component: {
              render(c) {
                http.request('GET', '/profile').then( async ({ data }) => {
                  console.log(data.profile.email)
                  if (data.profile.email === "vickysultan08@gmail.com") {
                      console.log('sip')
                      return c(HomeMentor);
                  } else {
                      return c(Home);
                  }
                });
              }
            },
          }
        ],
       beforeEnter: isAuthentication,
     }
});
```

The thing is, only the return component inside the conditional statement that cannot executed inside axios statement as the result below

[image]

While the return component inside the conditonal statement can be executed outside the axios statement like this

```js
children: [
        {
          path: '/',
          name: 'Dashboard',
            component: {
              render(c) {
                  a = 10
                  if (a === 10) {
                      console.log('sip')
                      return c(HomeMentor);
                  } else {
                      return c(Home);
                  }
              }
            },
          }
        ],
```

I'm quite new in Vue JS and have to continue other person's code. Any advice?

Comment: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/async-requests-inside-render-functions/11124

Comment: First, your render function isn't returning anything (you think you're returning a promise, but you're not). 2nd, your intended code won't work. AFAIK render functions must synchronously return a valid VNode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, render functions must be synchronous.

What you may be able to do instead is simply use an async function to return the component, ala [Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components) and [Lazy Loading Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html).

```js
const Dashboard = () => http.request('GET', '/profile').then(({ data }) => {
  console.log('profile email', data.profile.email)
  let isMentor = data.profile.email === 'vickysultan08@gmail.com'
  let componentPath = `./views/Home/${isMentor ? 'HomeMentor' : 'Home'}.vue`
  return import(componentPath) // chains in the "import" promise
})
```

and then in your route...

```js
component: Dashboard,
```

---

If lazy-loading the component isn't working for you, you could always try pre-loading it

```js
import http from './helpers/http';
import Home from './views/Home/Home.vue';
import HomeMentor from './views/Home/HomeMentor.vue';

const Dashboard = () => http.request('GET', '/profile').then(({ data }) => {
  let isMentor = data.profile.email === 'vickysultan08@gmail.com'
  return isMentor ? HomeMentor : Home
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it seems running well, but unfortunately it says "Error: "Cannot find module './views/Home/HomeMentor.vue'"

Comment: @VickySultan Does that component exist? That's the same as you have in your question

Comment: It does exist, i don't know the return import statement must be right, no?

Comment: @VickySultan I've added an alternative. Give that a try

Comment: Works like a charm! I was just thinking about that alternative condition, thank you!